# Windows Media Player file icons gone

Tags: windows-8.1, icons, windows-media-player, file-association, chkdsk

WMP file icons do not appear. WMP works fine and opens the files, the file associations exist, but the icons (not thumbnails) for the media files are gone. The blank (unknown file) icon is shown instead.

WMP is also gone from the list of Default programs.

What I've tried with no success:

- I found some registry entries that worked for some people and added
  them to the registry
- Disable and then enable WMP in Windows features
- Installed K-Lite Codec pack (I thought it might be bundled with
  icons)
- Downloaded WMP installation (doesn't work on Windows 8.1)
- Tried changing program access and computer defaults (WMP is listed
  there)

This is not a virus. I have a fairly new installation with a good AV. System Restore is not an option and I don't think it would work anyway.

The problem appeared after I ran a chkdsk on my SSD (I realize that that wasn't particularly smart).

Does anyone have a solution or an idea how to solve this? I would like to avoid reinstalling the OS.

I am running Windows 8.1.

Comment: Can you not even try a restore point?

Comment: I have some things installed (including Windows Update) after the last restore point and I know from experience that this does not end well. It corrupted my update databases once, so I don't want to risk it. (And I've read that people with this problem have tried it and it didn't work.)

Comment: Sounds like your default file extension keys are corrupt I would try restoring them.  I believe there is an existing question on now to do that

Comment: Solved the problem by replacing a DLL. Also, I ran System Restore and, as expected, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a different error ([How to repair .NET framework 4 installation on Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/729839/how-to-repair-net-framework-4-installation-on-windows-8)) where a DLL was corrupt, so I assumed this could be related to it. On another computer I found the `wmploc.dll` which contains the media file icons. I replaced the file and after restarting the icons were back. WMP is also back in the Default Programs list.