# How to repair .NET framework 4 installation on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8.1, .net-framework, dll

My `mscorlib.dll` seems to be corrupt. I tried reinstalling from the standalone .NET 4 installation package, but .NET 4 is integrated into Windows 8.1. Is there a way to repair it?

I have tried System Restore and sfc. They did not work.

I know I can reinstall the system, but I would like a less painful solution.

Comment: Actually 4.5 is integrated into Windows 8.0 not 4.0

Comment: I think both are. :)

Comment: That is not possible `4.5` replaces `4.0` they cannot co-exist at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I manually copied the corrupt file from a different computer with the same Windows installation. It took some permission changing, but I managed to replace the file.

Answer (score 5):

To repair use the following command at a command prompt (*with privileges*)

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

`RestoreHealth`: This switch option checks for component store corruption, records the corruption to the log file, and FIXES the image corruption using Windows Update. This should take around *10-15* minutes up to about an hour to finish depending on the level of corruption.

<sub>[Source](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/26512-dism-fixing-component-store-corruption-windows-8-a.html)</sub>

Comment: Tried that too. Did not work.